# Break down from range date to daily with high effeciency?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

The data have `start_date` and `end_date` like `2020-09-18` and `2020-09-28`. I need to break it down to daily which is `11` days including `2020-09-18`.

My solution is to create a date table with every single day.

```
with cte as(
select b.fulldate,
       count(1) over (partition by a,b,metric_c,metric_d) as count,
       a,b,
       metric_c, metric_d
from a 
join dim_date b
    on b.fulldate between a.start_date and a.end_date
)
select 
    fulldate,
    a,b,
    metric_c / count as metric_c, --maybe some cast or convert in here
    metric_d / count as metric_d
from cte
```

This is what I'm using currently. But is there a more effective way? If the table have 1,000,000 rows and maybe 10 metric, how can I get a better performance?

Thanks in advance anyway. Maybe there's some method that don't have to use an extra date table(which need some update if it's not enough date there), and have a really brilliant performance with millions data. If not, I'll keep using my method then.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the dim_date data model you have, as it has materialized the rows between the start_dates and end_dates.

The table DIM_DATE is an example of a confirmed dimension and it cab be used across any other subject areas in your reporting application that would need a date dimension.

I would check if in your DIM_DATE you have an index on the key which is being looked up (b.full_date) field.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be surprised if a recursive subquery had better performance if you have lots of dates and relatively short periods:

```
with cte as (
      select start_date, end_date,
             metric_a / (datediff(day, start_date, end_date) + 1) as metric_a,
             metric_b / (datediff(day, start_date, end_date) + 1) as metric_b
      from a
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, start_date), end_date, metric_a, metric_b
      from cte
      where start_date < end_date
     )
select *
from cte;
```

You can just add more metrics into the CTE as needed.

If any of the periods exceed 100 days, then you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)`.